# Unable to retrieve the attribute/field value of DynamoDB item in Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am developing an Android application using AWS services as back-end. Now I am doing something in the Lambda function when an item is added to a DynamoDB table. But I cannot retrieve the attribute value inside the lambda function. This is what I have done so far.

I created a DynamoDB table from the Mobile Hub application.

[image]

[image]

Table name is item.

In the lambda function I tried to retrieve the name value of the item table like this.

```
if (record.eventName == 'INSERT') {
     var name = record.dynamodb.item.Name.S
}
```

But it is saying that name is undefined. How can I fix it?

I tried this as well.

```
record.dynamodb['thegoodyardandroid-mobilehub-330286608-item'].Name.S
```

not working

Comment: Why don't you print the entire record you received, e.g. using JSON.stringify,  so that you can determine what it contains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event you get from a dynamo db stream is documented here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/eventsources.html#eventsources-ddb-update

Critically there is no `Item` key. For an `INSERT` event there's only a `NewImage` key.

So in your case you'll want:

```
var name = record.dynamodb.NewImage.Name.S
```